# How to prevent "this" from being rebound by event handlers

Tags: javascript, this

I've got a JS object, and one of it's prototype functions is an event handler for a click. When that function gets called, the `this` object is set to the element that the click is bound to. I'd like `this` to be the instance of the object that the function belongs to. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it? Solutions with or without jQuery are acceptable to me, although I'm sure that the rest of SO would appreciate a pure JS solution.

I've tried [`bind`ing the function to `this`](http://jsfiddle.net/04ykpsx1/), and it gets bound to the window rather than the instance of the object.

**Example of what I want**: In [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9yqm4ga/) (code duplicated below), I want an alert that says "Bark" when the button is clicked.

```
var Dog = function () {
    this.sound = "Bark";
}

Dog.prototype = {
    sayHello: function (e) {
        if (typeof this.sound == "undefined") {
            alert("I don't know what sound I should make!\n" + this);
        } else {
            alert(this.sound);
        }
    }
}

var d = new Dog();
var elem = document.getElementById("click");
elem.addEventListener("click", d.sayHello);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always intend for a function to be invoked with its own context, do the binding when the constructor runs instead:

```
var Dog = function () { 
  this.sound = "Bark";
  this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/04ykpsx1/1/

Something like [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) can reduce the boilerplate for you.

This is a better approach than forcing your callers to always call a function with `.bind`, because they shouldn't need to understand your class so deeply.

Comment: I like this method much more because it doesn't require me to bind every time, and because of what you said in the last sentence about how the caller shouldn't have to know how the method works and that they need to bind something. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it's my opinion that that's an "implementation detail" of your class-- no one should have to care whether or not you use `this` inside a function; it should just work as the caller expects. Cases where your class exposes a pseudo-static function that is intended to be called in multiple contexts are when the caller should have to `bind` manually.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.bind()` like this:

```
elem.addEventListener("click", d.sayHello.bind(d));
```

The manual way of doing it is with your own function:

```
elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    return d.sayHello();
});
```